# Remove outliers from pandas with different types

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, numeric, categorical-data, outliers

Currently working on a regression problem, I'm facing some issues in the performance of models. In order to have 'maybe' a better performance, I've some outliers that I'd like to remove.

Problem: Remove outliers from a dataframe containing different types.

The DF looks like:

```
   df.dtypes
CONTRACT_TYPE                           object
CONTRACT_COC                            object
ORIGINATION_DATE                datetime64[ns]
MATURITY_DATE                   datetime64[ns]
ORIGINAL_TERM                          float64
REMAINING_TERM                           int64
INTEREST_RATE_INTERNAL                 float64
INTEREST_RATE_FUNDING                  float64
```

However, after trying this code as shown bellow,  without success and even the zscore, I'm asking some help.

```
# Computing IQR
Q1 = df.quantile(0.25)
Q3 = df.quantile(0.75)
IQR = Q3 - Q1

df_out = df[~((df < (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR)) |(df > (Q3 + 1.5 * IQR))).any(axis=1)]
```

To summarize, I'd like to see in the plots (scatter, boxplot) a more 'normal' distribution without or with the less of outliers.

Please, do not hesitate if you need more information.

Comment: could you share some sample data?

Comment: without context, I could only suggest looking into [`scipy.stats.zscore`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.zscore.html). It calculates z-score for a given column (not the whole dataframe, at least I don't think so), and you could easily remove outliers based on the values (2.58 or 1.96)

Comment: Which columns are you trying to remove outliers from?  I imagine not the dates or object types?

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply! The aim was to remove outliers for all tables (but maybe it is a non sense). However, even if I want to remove outliers for numerical values only, How to do it without creating 2 dataframes (one with get_numeric and the other one with other types). Therefore, in this case I have to merge them and data won't be in the same position? If you have any clues, please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I assume that your data distribution is Normal.
Here is a great strategy for removing outliers.

1. Make a Pandas Dataframe with all numeric features, which has outliers.
2. Use [sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) on your Dataframe. It standardize features by removing the mean and scaling to unit variance. The implementation is as easy as follows;

   ```
   # Declare Sklearn standard_scaler
   standard_scaler = StandardScaler(copy=True, with_mean=True, with_std=True)        

   # Fitting
   standard_scaler.fit(x_train_df)        

   # Transforming
   x_train_normal_scaled_df = standard_scaler.transform(x_train_df)        

   # Fitting and Transforming together 
   x_train_normal_scaled_df = x_scaler_lev1.fit_transform(x_train_df)        

   # Inverting the transformed data back.
   x_train_df = standard_scaler.inverse_transform()

   print(x_train_normal_scaled_df.describe())
   x_train_normal_scaled_df.plot()
   ```
3. You should find out how much of your data is outlier. [Empirical Rule of Normal Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule) can help here.

[image: Empirical Rule]

Experimentally, I always choose the data in the range of 3 times of standard deviation as my main data and out of this range would be the outlier. Normal distribution would guarantee that the main data have about 99.73% of information.